# What does "is { }" mean?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I see the following code sometimes, and have no idea what the expression is actually testing.

```cs
public static void Something(string[] value)
{
   if (value is { })
   {
      DoSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's just the empty property pattern in C# 8, meaning the value not `null`. It matches any value type or reference type. As  Panagiotis Kanavos notes in the comments, this is equivalent to the good old `value is object` check which has been in C# for a long time.

Generally if you were to specify a property, then it would match or not. This esoteric example illustrates that:

```
if (value is { Length: 2 })
{
   // matches any object that isn't `null` and has a property set to a length of 2
}
```

The property patterns work best and are most clear when comparing with other patterns in cases such as `switch` expressions.

Comment: what does mean empty object in this case? empty string, white space?

Comment: it's quite crazy that `string s = "s"; if(s is { })` will return true

Comment: @OlegI no it's not. `s` is definitelly not null. `is {}` is shorthand for `is object` and strings *can* be cast to object.

Comment: @OlegI how so? its a valid reference so it matches.

Comment: This type of expessions are called Recursive patterns and they can go really crazy (like `if (this is Box (var metadata, var _) { Label: "Books" } box) { ... }`.. See my example demo on [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PWrGitHub194238/Capgemini.NET/blob/master/CSharp80/15.RecursivePatterns/Program.cs).

Comment: @Eatos good to note. i haven't written any yet but the toll collector example i saw looks amazong

Comment: Its a new world where structs can be null and references cannot be null, switch statements are reversed and various `!`, `!!`, `?` and `??` before and after properties mean different things. When will the syntactic sugar high end?

Comment: Is it the same as `value != null`?

Comment: Because _value_ could have is own implementation of `!=` it could be different. But it is the same as `value is not null`.

Comment: It does not appear as if "is {}" is a perfect equivalent to "is object". I just replaced "{ }" with "object" in my code and some red squiggles appeared under one line of code and the tooltip stated that "object does not contain a definition for ...".

Comment: @RayGoudie true; they aren't exactly equivalent; `x is {} y` results in a `y` that is the same type as `x` (or possibly null, i.e. if `x` is a `string`, `y` is a `string?`). `x is object y` results in a `y` that is `x` boxed as an `object`; to get it back you'd have to cast and call your things e.g. `if("" is object y) ((string)y).Length ...`. It would probably be more helpful as an explanation to say `x is {} y` is like `x is var y`, because devs are familiar with the concept that `var` means "the compiler works out the type"

Answer (score 20):

While Daniel's answer is right, I think it might be useful to add some context about *why* you may see the empty property pattern in use. Consider this example controller method that needs some validation done:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, ...) 
{
    if (ValidateId(id) is { } invalid)
        return invalid;
    ...
}
```

In the above, `ValidateId()` could return null or an instance of `BadObjectRequestResult`. If the former is returned, the validation is successful and moves on to the rest of the body of `Update`. If the latter is returned, `is {}` is **true** (i.e. of course an instance of `BadObjectRequestResult` is an `object`), and the validation fails.

Nicely, out of this we've also provided a variable name, `invalid`,  which we can return immediately. Without that we'd need slightly more verbose code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, ...) 
{
    var invalid = ValidateId(id);
    if (invalid != null)
        return invalid;
    ...
}
```

Whether one is more readable or the other is up to the reader, I've just presented one way the empty property pattern can be used.

Comment: In that case one should use `is object invalid`, not `is {} invalid`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that would not work in this case because a return of `IActionResult` is required (well technically `Task<IActionResult>`). If we go with your style, the `if` has the same result but `invalid` will be an `object` so this won't compile.