# C# While Loop Null Check Pattern?

Tags: c#, null-check

I wrote code like this

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("SomeFilePath"))
{
    while(reader.ReadLine() is string currentLine)
    {}
}
```

Then My IDE Rider suggested me below with comment "Use null check pattern"

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("SomeFilePath"))
{
    while(reader.ReadLine() is {} currentLine)
    {}
}
```

I thought that would make syntax error, but it didn't

That Line Of Code does her job nicely.

So my question is what is {} in **while(reader.ReadLine is {} currentLine)**

maybe it's kind of Record Expression?

Also I could not figure out why **{} currentLine** is better than **string currentLine**

Thank you for your help

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849590/how-should-i-interpret-the-null-check-pattern-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "is { }" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417114/what-does-is-mean)

Comment: I personally perfer the first version - in the second version you need to know the type returned by `ReadLine()` to know the type of `currentLine`. Arguably you should know that, but in terms of readability putting `string` makes it clearer. I apply the same argument to using `while (reader.ReadLine() is var currentLine)`

Comment: It depends if you care about the type. That is a context dependent question IMO. Rider is more generally opinionated. It would be nice if you could write `reader.ReadLine() is not null currentLine` but that is invalid syntax.

Comment: can you try this on your Rider `reader?.ReadLine() is string currentLine` this will null check the `reader` and return a `boolean` right away, to avoid `null` pass to `currentLine`. I believe Rider will stop warn you.

Answer (score 2):

`is {}` is used to match an expression against a pattern.It uses the [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns) (For `C#` versions >= `7.0` )

So basically this line of code:

```
while(reader.ReadLine() is {} currentLine)
```

checks if the output of `reader.Readline()` matches any pattern(i.e. not null). If it does, then assign the output to the variable `currentLine` .

Comment: better link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns

Comment: Thanks, I have update it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: `{ }` is for pattern matching or `Null` checking, shorthand for `If else` statement.

**Swift** have the `guard statement`. Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics have  `Guard Class`, that is to highlight the important of `null` checking. The `{ }` can also understand like a `guard`

> So my question is what is {} in while(reader.ReadLine is {}
> currentLine)

The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible with a given type. your IDE Rider *over reacting* of comparing `reader.ReadLine`() with `string` both can be null, **VS2022** give it a pass because [`ReadLine`() is read `null` if the end of the input stream is reached.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-7.0#returns)

> Also I could not figure out why {} currentLine is better than string
> currentLine

[Working with Null in .NET 6 and C# 10](https://youtu.be/-bn4e5xUEeM?t=1120) 
I believe Rider want to make sure all cases are covered with `{ }`, in most case with **Reference type** the IDE will give you warning of *`Null` checking*, to bypass this instead cheking with `If else` you just need `{ }`

Comment: In the very unlikely event the return type of `ReadLine` were to change from `string` to perhaps  `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` the null check would continue to work. Is that good or bad? Rider has an opinion.

Comment: `byte` is not reference type, it will act differently, IDE not allow you to have a null value type, like `int = null`, but now after C# 6 it is allow `int? = null`. so in most case with Reference type the IDE will give you warning of `Null` checking, to bypass this instead of type `IF ELSE` you just need `{ }`

Comment: @tom301 My bad but, I don't think the return of `ReadLine` will be changing. Your comment is right. However my point was, who should decide if checking the type is important, in the general case?

Comment: `string` is reference type that is why IDE warn. In most case, **coder should**, when dealing with `null`, this is not new in **Swift** they have the `guard statement`. Now, in VS2022 Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics have  `Guard Class`, that is to highlight the important of `null` checking