# C# - How can I check if a field exists before trying to query it in a JSON JToken?

Tags: c#, json, null, json.net

I am pulling down JSON data from a website and some of the fields are optional, meaning they do not always exist. When I try to query them, my program breaks. I believe I am checking for nulls incorrectly.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "myToken");
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://app.website.com/data/");
                    
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("getData.json?thing=abc").Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    if (result.HasValues)
    {
        var count = result.SelectTokens("results.main[*].item").Count();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            var total = result.SelectTokens("results.main[*].item.total").First() != null ? result.SelectTokens("results.main[*].item.total").First().ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

It breaks when I try to query for `total` even though I'm checking for nulls. Since it's not always a guarantee that `total` is returned, how can I check for it first?

The JSON array looks like this. Sometimes `total` exists and other times it doesn't.

```
{
    "results": {
        "copyright": "Copyright (c)",
        "main": [{
            "item": {
                "name": fruit,
                "date": 1900-01-01,
                "total": 123456
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which C# / .NET version are you using?  Also, will the `results.main[*]` array always have only one item?  If not, do you only care about the first item, or the first item for which `item.total` is present?

Comment: I'm on 4.5.2 right now but I can upgrade if needed. `results.main[*]` will always have one `item` but it will also have other fields at the same level that have different names like `results.main[*].history`. I can access those separately by just switching from `item` to `history` in my query. My main concern is trying to pull optional fields (such as `total`) within `item`. `total` is not always guaranteed to be there.

Comment: 4.5.2 is fine.  C# 8.0 introduces additional syntax sugar for checking for null (e.g. [`is {} total`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60417114)) but you can certainly check for null easily in any C# version.

Comment: your json is not valid , what are you trying to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you are trying to get the value of the first `"total"` by calling `SelectTokens("...").First()`.  The extension method [`Enumerable.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first) will throw an exception if the enumerable is empty and so is not appropriate to use when querying for optional values.  Instead, you could use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) or [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-8.0).  ([`Enumerable.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) should be avoided when you only need to check if an enumerable has content, as it will enumerate the entire sequence.)

Thus your code can be simplified to:

```
var total = (string)result.SelectTokens("results.main[*].item.total").SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(total))
{
    // Process the total somehow.
}
```

That being said, since you are expecting only one item in the `results.main[*]` array, you could just use [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) instead of `SelectTokens()`:

```
var total = (string)result.SelectToken("results.main[0].item.total") ?? string.Empty;
```

Alternatively, if you the `results.main[*]` might have multiple items and only some have totals, you could use the JSONPath conditional operator to select them:

```
var items = result.SelectTokens("results.main[?(@.item.total)].item");
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var name = (string)item["name"];
    var total = (decimal)item["total"];
    Console.WriteLine("name = {0}, total = {1}", name, total);
}
```

Notes:

- Calling `SelectToken()` or `SelectTokens()` does incur a performance cost, so I would recommend against making the same query more than once and instead save intermediate results in local variables.
- As explained in *[Avoiding Deadlock with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32195595)*, `httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;` can sometimes result in deadlocks, so you might want to rewrite your method to be asynchronous.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xOTzq3).

Answer (score 1):

your json is not valid. But if you know how to fix it, you can get your data in one line of code.

```
int? total=JObject.Parse(json)
                  .SelectToken("results.main")
                  ?.Select(j => (int?) j.SelectToken("item.total"))
                  .FirstOrDefault()
```

It will be working without any exception if even the list "main" is not exist.

but if you need to know if an array exist and has at least one item

```
    bool? isArrayExist = JObject.Parse(json)
    .SelectToken("results.main")
    ?.Any();
```

P.S. All explanations you can find  @dbc answer